# Change Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: installation, windows, hard-drive, format

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. And now I want to use Windows as Ubuntu have lots of fail
and my laptop is all time is overheated. I mean by overheated that you can't touch fan postion because it's so hot.

Now I want to use Windows, but I wonder is there a way to install Windows and remove Ubuntu without formate my hard drive and songs, music, documents stay in drive so I don't need to formate all hard to make it NTFS again.

Comment: are you dual booting?
not installing the gpu driver in the last tab of software sources can cause overheating on some mobile hardware

Comment: This can't be done without reformatting your drive. Windows does not like Ubuntu file system. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should backup to an external drive of some sort, and re-install Windows. If you do not have access to an external drive, then you could always make a small partition, back up your data to that partition, and install Windows on the leftover chunk of your hard drive. There is no way to install Windows over Ubuntu without formatting, because Ubuntu natively uses an EXT4 filesystem. Because Windows uses NTFS as it's filesystem, you have to reformat your EXT4 filesystem to NTFS format.